# AppleScript and non-scriptable applications

Tags: applescript

I'm wondering how can I script applications which has no dictionary. All information that I've found tells me nothing. But my experience says me that there is a way.
For example:

```
tell application "Firefox"
    return count of windows
end tell
```

Will work. And it will work with "Opera" and other applications without dictionary at all. So the questions are:
1) Why does it work?
2) What else work in such a manner? Is there a list of all such actions?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can to some extent script applications without an applescript dictionary by using 'tell application "System Events"'

```
tell application "Keynote" activate 
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {command down} 
end tell
end tell
```

This example activates Keynote and then copies the current selection. You can use similar code in many applications even if they don't have an applescript dictionary provided you also have the "Enable access for assistive devices" option checked in the "Universal Access" System Preference.

**Edit:**

This document gives some details of how Cocoa provides some support for Applscript in all applications:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_about_apps/SAppsAboutApps.html

Under the heading Built-in Support for Standard and Text Suites

Comment: I know that. But my example doesn't use Universal Access and GUI Scripting. So it uses some other sort of things whic I try to find. And Universal Access is disabled on my Mac

Answer (score 3):

You *can* open the scripting dictionary of FireFox. Just open AppleScript Editor and go File → show dictionary, and choose FireFox from the list.

It just shows a very rudimentary dictionary. What happens is that the system library provides at least a basic set of commands (called the Standard Suite) to any Carbon or Cocoa app. This is what contains the definitions of `window` you used.

As Ian already wrote, in order to do more with such an app, you use the so-called *UI scripting* via `System Events`. 
This [nice website](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html) is a good place to start.